# Cannot compile JAX-WS: module not found: jakarta.xml.bind

Tags: java, jaxb, jax-ws, java-11, jakarta-migration

I want to use JAX-WS in Java 11 but when I try to compile, it shows me:

```
module not found: jakarta.xml.bind
```

[image]

I am importing JAX-WS libraries in my pom:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.xml.ws-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

The pom library tree:

[image]

The module-info.class (jakarta.xml.bind):

[image]

And my module-info.java:

```
module test.jakarta {
    requires jakarta.xml.bind;
}
```

I'm importing the libraries in my pom and adding the requires clause in my module-info.java but I can't compile. Can anybody help me?

Comment: What about importing [the dependencies from this website](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jaxb-ri/)?

Comment: Unfortunately, the result is the same...

Comment: remove <scope>runtime</scope> from one of dependency you listed and add Jaxb dependency to maven of equivalent version of jax-ws.

Comment: <dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
</dependency>

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by upgrading the library version (from `2.3.2` in my case) to `4.0.0`